# how to order a choicefiled in django model

Tags: django

I have a choice filed and i need to sort it based on the order in  CHOICES tuple  and this model.py:

```py
class MeetingMember(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
    ("H", "Host"),
    ("A", "Accepted"),
    ("R", "Rejected"),
    ("I", "Invited" )
    )
    
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=CHOICES, default="I")
```

i have already tried meta ordering :

```py
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('status',)
```

but it is not working i need to sort it in `Host,Accepted,Rejected,Invited`

Comment: The `status` field could be changed to an IntegerField and the choices could then be incrementing integers to make ordering easy?

Comment: Is there any other way to sort it ?i need this logic in frontend

Comment: Should this not be the default ordering? Can you give an example of where you need it in the frontend?

Comment: As you said , i changed  the choices to integer and it works!many tnxs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to exploit the `Replace` function (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#replace). The strategy is to annotate a new field with a value built in a way that its alphabetical order matches the custom order you want in the original field:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Replace

# This generates a dictionary like {'0': 'H', '1': 'A', ...}
mapped_choices = {str(n): CHOICES[n][0] for n in range(len(CHOICES))}

# For each mapped choice we create a replacer
replacers = [
    Replace('status_for_ordering', Value(original), Value(replacement)) 
    for replacement, original in mapped_choices.items()
]

qs = MeetingMember.objects.all().annotate(status_for_ordering=F('status'))
for replacer in replacers:
    qs = qs.annotate(status_for_ordering=replacer)

# Of course here you can still filter or do other operations before ordering
qs = qs.order_by('status_for_ordering')
```

This solution should work for your example but of course would need some adjustments in case the replacements starts to conflict each others (f.i. if one of your original status values contains a digit).